# How to select a specific column that contains a string using regex?

Tags: regex, text-processing, emeditor

I am using EmEditor to do some text-processing as the file that I am processing is a large file. I am using regex to select one column at a time whilst at the same time searching for a string.

I am currently using the regex code that highlights the rows that do not contain the string that I am searching for. But I need a regex code that could only highlight the contents of the column (one column at a time) that doesn't contain the string that I am searching for.

For instance, I am currently using the following regex code that highlights the rows that doesn't contain the string `12345`
`^((?!12345).)*$`
However, I am looking for a regex code that could highlight say the 10th column that doesn't contain the string say `12345` and replace the other contents of the same column with a character of my choice. The string that I am looking for varies every time as well as the column is different each time.

My file contains the following and I am searching for `12345` in the first column:

```
   12345,6457,789
   4568,21231,657
```

The desired output after finding for `12345` is that the contents of first column are selected/marked in this case are `123` and `4568`. Once these are selected/marked I can then replace these with a character of my choice by using the find and replace option in EmEditor.
Second instance, using the same example above I am searching for `456` in the third column. The desired output after finding for `456` is that the contents of third column are selected/marked in this case are `789` and `657`.
It would be great to have a regex code that has a modifiable column position and (modifiable) string that I am looking for something similar to the `awk` codes, for instance, `awk $1` or `awk ($1,$3)` for a modifiable column position.

Thanks for your kind reply @nonForgivingJesus. I will try Vim as it looks promising. Is there a possibility where it replaces the matches with 'a' and mismatches with shifting the mismatched content to right simultaneously shifting the rest of the columns to right but leaving the top row untouched and replacing the empty spaces in column 1 with 'b'? For instance,

```
   12345,6457,789,21231,657
   6457,21231,657
   12345,789,21231
```

The output for when looking for 12345 should be:

```
a,6457,789,21231,657
b,6457,21231,657
a,789,21231
```

The output for when looking for 6457 should be:

```
a,a,789,21231,657
b,a,21231,657
a,b,789,21231
```

The final output should look something after looking for 789, 21231 and then 657 as below:

```
a,a,a,a,a
b,a,b,a,a
a,b,a,a,b,
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you can map commands to keys, like Vim does, and pass text you processing to another program, like Vim, than, i think, this is best way to check columns for desired matches.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Would you give me an example of Vim using the example given above? And can I use Vim code in EmEditor?

Comment: i will post it like answer

Comment: Much appreciated!!

Comment: i updated my answer

Comment: You didn't mention CSV mode so I'm wondering if you used CSV mode, which turns your CSV file into a table for easy selection of columns. If not, it's under Edit | CSV | Comma separated.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Vim, you can enter "Visual Block mode" via `Ctrl+V` and then go to the end of the file, by pressing `G` (if you see capital char -- this is `Shift+*char*`. In this case `Shift+g`) and then select text within column borders (if you didn't use Vim before, you can use arrows on keyboard, but more Vim'ish way to do it is via `hjkl`).

Also you should set highlight mode in Vim, pressing `:` and writing `set hlsearch`

Then you should press `/` to enter the search and type text you want to search (you can use regex here, but vim, as I know, natively do not support PCRE flavor. Out of the box it supports [basic and extended regexes](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html), but I believe it can be enhanced with plugins). This will search entire selection:

[image: 12345 search]
[image]

Also you can pass entire selection to another program, pressing `:` and then `!` (`:` enters command mode and `!` creates terminal and passes selected text to program, that follows the `!`) :

[image: pass selection]

Here I pass selection to `cut` program, setting column delimeter to `,` (`-d,`) and requesting only second column in output (`-f2`).
You can map routine actions via `:map`, but you better read about this by yourself.

I suggest you [image: this] playlist about optimizing life with Vim, I personally like it.

P.S You can also do arithmetic on text via `Ctrl+a` (addition) `Ctrl+x` (substraction), but this is out of scope of the question :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to replace the matches with 'a' and mismatches by shifting the mismatched content to right simultaneously shifting the rest of the columns to right but leaving the top row untouched and replacing the empty spaces in column 1 with 'b'? See my original question for an example.

Comment: @user3441801 yes, Vim even have its own language, but i didn't ever use it. I suggest you to make several mappings (or recording macros, via `q` command) and then execute them on the selection. I suggest you to go through [small online course](https://www.openvim.com/) or launch `vimintro`, to read about most use-cases. But for now it's hard for me to think exact solution to your problem, sorry...

Comment: Thanks @nonForgivingJesus for your suggestion will try it out.

Comment: @user3441801 you are welcome :) But yesterday I mistakenly said to read `vimintro`, but it's actually called `vimtutor`

Comment: That's ok I will refer to ```vimtutor``` instead. Thanks.